# Tranparent div in div with background image with rounded corners

Tags: html, css

i have transparent div on the bottom of div with image backgrounnd. Everything is OK, but in the rounded corners of the transparent part the background image "shines trough".

There is link to fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jw1k98dt/

There is my html:

```
   <div id="zkus">
        <div id="zkus_popis"></div>
    </div>
```

There is my css:

```
#zkus{
    background: url('test.jpg');
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    background-size:  100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px   #d1cfcf;
   /*  box-shadow:  0 0 10px #5c5c5c;*/

    border-radius: 12px 12px 15px 15px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
   /* border: 1px solid #8d8d8d;*/
   margin: 0 12px 10px 10px;
}

#zkus_popis{
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
   border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks.. :)

Comment: The only solution I've found is to use an `img` tag instead of a background image. So put another div in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success with either of two different methods:

1. Apply [`backface-visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) to `#zkus_popis`:

   ```css
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   ```

   [WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jw1k98dt/14/)
2. Apply a small [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to `#zkus_popis`:

   ```css
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(1px);
   -o-transform: translateZ(1px);
   transform: translateZ(1px);
   ```

   [WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jw1k98dt/18/)

Comment: the above is true for webkit - however firefox will still show the same bug.

Comment: @easwee Agreed. This doesn't seem to help for Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

This was reported as bug many times before (see this report and linked duplicates https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23166, firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=921341 ), since even using `background-clip: border-box` fails to clip the content correctly leaving a few pixels to bleed.

You can solve it **webkit** based browsers by applying (triggering browser's 3D acceleration):

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/8up9pkfo/

In Firefox seems like they are aware of the issue, but still waiting another bug fix that is related to the same code - I can't provide a pure CSS workaround for Firefox, however you could try to use [SVG clipping](http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/firefox-img-rounded-corners-svg?blog=2) to solve it in Firefox..

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a black box-shadow to try and mask that background image. Its a little hacky, but it works.

```
#zkus{
background: url('http://zkusebny2.chlupac.com/images/test.jpg');
width: 200px;
height: 180px;
background-size:  100%;
border-radius: 12px 12px 15px 15px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 0px 1px #000000;
margin: 0 12px 10px 10px;
}

    #zkus_popis{
    width: 200px;
    height: 38px;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Note: This can be a solution, but it impacts the visual styling - so it's not without drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

is a solution, but it is not very reliable, because for exaple, if i have gradient background, it looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/jw1k98dt/30/ (There is something black in the corner).

If you set the same radius on both divs, it looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/jw1k98dt/31/. So what radius should the corners have?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #zkus{
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    }
```